# SOAP message not including operation name

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am integrating with a 3rd party WSDL using `WebServiceGatewaySupport` and `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.maven-jaxb2-plugin` version 0.15.1. The WSDL works correctly on SoapUI, but not directly within Spring Boot.

After adding extra bindings and namespace declarations, my calls still fail with `Method 'ns2:carsRequest' not implemented: method name or namespace not recognized`.

I realized that my code is not wrapping the request element with the operation, meaning that the following message succeeds in SOAP UI but `<pai:GetListCars>` is missing in the payload generated from my Java code:

```xml
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:pai="http://my-endpoint.com">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <pai:GetListCars> <!-- line missing -->
            <ns2:carsRequest xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                <lang>EN</lang>
            </ns2:carRequest>
        </pai:GetListCars> <!-- line missing -->
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here is the corresponding WSDL:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"
                  xmlns:impl="http://my-endpoint.com"
                  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  targetNamespace="http://my-endpoint.com">
    <wsdl:types>
        <schema targetNamespace="http://my-endpoint.com"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            <complexType name="CarsRequest">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="lang" nillable="true" type="soapenc:string"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <complexType name="CarsResponse">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="ErrorMessage" nillable="true" type="soapenc:string"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="GetListCarsResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="getListCarsReturn" type="impl:CarsResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetListCarsRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="carRequest" type="impl:CarsRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="Garage">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetListCars" parameterOrder="frnreq">
            <wsdl:input message="impl:GetListCarsRequest" name="getListVehiclesRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="impl:GetListCarsResponse" name="getListVehiclesResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="GarageSoapBinding"
                  type="impl:Garage">
        <wsdlsoap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetListCars">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input name="getListVehiclesRequest">
                <wsdlsoap:body
                        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                        namespace="http://my-endpoint.com" use="encoded"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="getListVehiclesResponse">
                <wsdlsoap:body
                        encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                        namespace="http://my-endpoint.com" use="encoded"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="GarageService">
        <wsdl:port binding="impl:GarageSoapBinding" name="Garage">
            <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8888"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I do not want to change the source WSDL file, is there a way to construct add the missing lines? Or maybe use a different library?

Answer (score 0):

In your WSDL's  tag have no GetListCarsResponse and GetListCarsRequest.

The **jaxb** read only from a schema not a whole WSDL.

So you need to change your schema.xsd file like this.
Try again compile the server source and get the new WSDL from server.
To paste into the client source compile it then call Soap API.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://my-endpoint.com"
    xmlns:tns="http://my-endpoint.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
    <xs:complexType name="CarsRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="lang" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="CarsResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ErrorMessage" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="GetListCarsRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="tns:CarsRequest"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="GetListCarsResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="tns:CarsResponse"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

New WSDL will be like this.

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:sch="http://my-endpoint.com"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://my-endpoint.com"
    targetNamespace="http://my-endpoint.com">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://my-endpoint.com">
            <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            <xs:complexType name="CarsRequest">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="lang" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="CarsResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ErrorMessage" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="GetListCarsRequest">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="name" type="tns:CarsRequest"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="GetListCarsResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="name" type="tns:CarsResponse"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="GetListCarsResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:GetListCarsResponse" name="GetListCarsResponse"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetListCarsRequest">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:GetListCarsRequest" name="GetListCarsRequest"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="Garage">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetListCars">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:GetListCarsRequest" name="GetListCarsRequest"></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:GetListCarsResponse" name="GetListCarsResponse"></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="GarageSoap11" type="tns:Garage">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetListCars">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input name="GetListCarsRequest">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="GetListCarsResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="GarageService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:GarageSoap11" name="GarageSoap11">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8888/service/garage"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```